# Do I need to let my Anti-Virus scan "C:\Documents and Settings" on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, kaspersky

I have Kaspersky Internet Security 2011 running on my Windows 7 PC. I've noticed that whenever I do a Full System Scan it scans everything including "C:\Documents and Settings" (which can take up to 12 Hours to complete). Now as far as I know, "C:\Documents and Settings" just reroutes to "C:\Users" on Windows Vista/7, so am I not effectively scanning "C:\Users" twice?

Is it safe to set Kaspersky not to scan "C:\Documents and Settings" thus lessen the time it takes to scan my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since `C:\Documents and Settings` is sure to represent `C:\Users`, you can safely leave it unchecked. I really hope you haven't paid for such a software.

Answer (score 0):

(I didn't know that KIS 2011 was out already. :O)

If I recall correctly, it will only scan  C:\Users once, in the case of Windows XP and Vista.